# Angular.js date filter showing month ahead?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So looking at the documentation, I couldn't see how I could easily add the next month in something like this:

```
{{ item.lastUpdateDay|date : 'MMMM' }}
```

Seems like I should be able to add a (+) or (-) to get that. So if based on todays date, traditionally it would show 'September', but I want it to read that date and display the following month.

What am I missing here?

Thanks much.

Comment: update your Date, answers available on how to do that

Comment: what are you referring to? not seeing what you are referring too..

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of work with dates I recommend using moment.js

if not you should do it from controller, something like this:

```
$scope.updateDate = function(){
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
  return $scope.lastUpdateDay = $filter('date')(date, 'MMMM');
}
```

Comment: I thought of using moment, but almost all my needs are satisfied so far with angular. Just presuming that there is a way that I am not finding that angular can do it inline with a filter or so. Additionally, this code is inside a template that is internal to a larger view and that lastUpdateDay is a property pulled from an API.

Comment: Not sure what lies behind your code, but "Best practices for AngularJS generally state that you should write your own models--objects that represent your business domain--and attach them to the scope.", maybe this variable coming from API, but you can somehow reach the parent controller (with $parent).

Answer (score 1):

OR, as you prefer the inline method, you can make you own date filter :

```
angular
   .module('myApp')
   .filter('myDate', myDate);

function myDate($filter){
   return function(date, format){  
   date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
   return $filter('date')(date, format);
  }
}
```

And in your template :

```
{{lastUpdateDate | myDate: 'MMMM'}}
```

Do not, forget to use two letter prefix on your own filters (my here ...)